# select external elements by its internal tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

is it possible to select external element by it's descendent elements ,
Quetions comes from the need to apply 1 style sheet to 2 diffrent dymins pages of same wrapper.

page 1

```
<div id="api">
 <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

page 2

```
<div id="api">
 <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

i'd like to select api element by internal element class.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `:has()` pseudo-class in the CSS specification, but it has not (and probably won't be) been implemented in any browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Since your markup is generated dynamically, it should be relatively easy to set the wrapper classes dynamically instead, e.g.

```
<div id="api" class="list list_a">
...
</div>
```

Comment: i can only add css , i dont have any way to effect the given html.

Comment: @Shl if absolutely necessary, you can also use javascript to add the necessary classes